# Selenium tests running too fast, not waiting for the radio button to be selected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Grid and WebDriver 2.48.2 test that runs too fast. The majority of the time the test stops because a radio button isn't selected prior to a button being pressed.

The radio buttons are setup using JavaScript based on a JSON file to create any number of them within a section on the fly. Once the continue button is clicked that section is destroyed and a new one created with new radio buttons.

I tried an implicit wait with no success.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The only solution that is working for me is a delay to allow enough time for the radio button to be clicked.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("radiobuttonid")).click();
Thread.sleep(delay);
```

But in my opinion this isn't an ideal solution, it's possible the delay may not be long enough or that it's too long, wasting time; there could be any number of radio buttons so the time will increase exponentially.

I've tried setting up various [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) with different [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) but with no success.

I've tried waiting for the radio button to be created since it may not exist (`presenceOfElementLocated` & `elementToBeClickable`). I've tried waiting for it to be selected (`elementToBeSelected`).

I'm having trouble finding exactly what the expected conditions are supposed to do since the descriptions are brief and open to misinterpretation.

Ideally, I want the test to continue soon after the radio button is clicked. If possible, what's the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

L.Bar's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33128304/1197834) below didn't work for me, but it was very helpful to determine that the radio buttons exist, just that the continue button is being clicked before the radio button has a chance to be selected.

**EDIT 2**

This is just to expand on Jeremiah correct answer. I put the code into a method to make it reusable.

```
private static Predicate<WebDriver> forceSelectionOfElement (final String id)
{
    return new Predicate<WebDriver>()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver arg0)
        {
            WebElement element = arg0.findElement(By.id(id));                
            boolean rval = element.isSelected();

            if (!rval) {
                element.click();
            }

            return rval;
        }
    };
}
```

Usage

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(forceSelectionOfElement("q___01_02_01___1___a"));
```

Remember to import this namespace, it took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out I imported the wrong one :)

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
```

Comment: Good question. Things like this can be a pain to figure out. What language are you using? It looks like Java. Please add the relevant programming language tag to the question. What changes when the radio button is clicked? Anything you can detect?

Comment: @JeffC It is Java, I added the tag. Nothing changes when the radio button is clicked. Once the continue button is clicked it performs actions on the radio buttons to see if it should continue to the next section.

Comment: Just to make the function more useful, you could do forceSelectionOfElement (final By by) instead of using string argument (this way you can choose xpath, id, or css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, but in my case my 'click' event was lost somewhere.  My  test would proceed, the click code would trigger, but the state of the element would never visibly change and the test would fail.  I ended up leveraging the looping behavior of the WebDriverWait by adding a custom predicate that is a bit more persistent about the selected state.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        final By lookup = By.id("radio");
        LOG.debug("Wait for radio to be clickable.");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(lookup)); //I assume this implies visibility.
        LOG.debug("Element clickable.  Proceeding into click behavior.");
        wait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                LOG.debug("Resolving 'myId' Element");
                WebElement radio = arg0.findElement(lookup);                
                boolean rval = radio.isSelected();
                LOG.debug("Element Resolved and has a state of " + (rval ? "selected" : "not selected"));
                if (!rval) {
                    LOG.debug("Clicking on the Element!");
                    radio.click();
                }
                //If we return false we will loop.  So the first time through we let this click the radio for us.
                //Second time through we should find that the element is clicked.  If it's not we click it again until it represents the state we're wanting.
                return rval;;
            }});
```

The custom predicate will

1. Resolve the WebElement
2. Capture the current Selected status
3. Click the WebElement if it is not selected
4. Return the current selected status.

So this should not allow the test to proceed until the clicked state of the element is what I want it to be.  So far it's done basically what I've wanted.

It's also worth noting that Thread.sleep is seen as not the best practice for selenium interactions.  This is what the ExplicitWait concept is meant to account for.  I've linked one of the latest topics in which I'm aware of this being discussed.

[Thread.sleep works but implicit wait, webdriverwait and fluent wait does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977691/thread-sleep-works-but-implicit-wait-webdriverwait-and-fluent-wait-does-not/32982180)

Best of Luck!

Comment: This worked for me. The only change I did was put it into a method. I'm assuming this will work with checkboxes as well.

Comment: Probably.  The one thing that I've been concerned with is the possibility that the check state doesn't toggle before the wait loops.  If you see that behavior you can use wait.pollingEvery(long duration, TimeUnit unit) to slow the loop a bit.   I haven't seen that behavior yet, but I do believe it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

My way to do it:

```
public bool IsElementPresent(By by, IWebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public bool IsElementPresent(By by, IWebDriver driver, int sec)
{
    bool itemExist = false;

    itemExist = IsElementPresent(by, driver);
    while (!itemExist && sec >= 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        itemExist = IsElementPresent(by, driver);
        sec--;
    }

    if (sec == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Calling to test if exist

```
//Checking if element exist 10 sec
if(IsElementPresented(By.Id("radiobuttonid"),driver,10))
{
//element exist click on it
}
else
{
//didn't exist.
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but it didn't work for me. This was very helpful in that I think this proves that the radio button exists, it's just not being selected before the continue button is clicked. I did change the Thread.sleep to 50ms since 1s would have been too long (the "delay" in my post was 500ms).

Comment: This code can all be replaced with a WebDriverWait and `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator)`.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you explored ExpectedConditions, have you tried `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected()`? You should be able to detect if the radio button is selected and then move forward. Try something like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.id("radiobuttonid"));
radio.click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ID of message element")));
// do stuff
```

EDIT

Changed code after more info from OP

Comment: I did try that (I mentioned it in my question), it didn't work. :( But I'm glad to know I was using it properly.

Comment: If this code passes, it indicates that the radio button is selected. Where does the error/failure occur after this code?

Comment: I don't visually see the radio button selected. Also, if the user doesn't select a radio button there is a message indicating this, I see this message being displayed. The test then times out.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on the line after the `.click()`? Does the radio eventually get clicked it just takes a while?

Comment: It does eventually get clicked, if I put a `Thread.sleep` after `driver.findElement(By.id("radiobuttonid")).click();` it works every time.

Comment: So your wait should be to wait for the message to disappear. You can do that with `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ID of message"))`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It's an error message stating that the user needs to make a selection. Not making a selection is what causes the test to fail.

Comment: Correct... so once a selection is made, I'm assuming that the error message will disappear. When that message disappears, you should be able to assume that the radio button is (fully) selected.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. But the message doesn't disappear :(

Comment: I don't suppose you can post a link to the page so we can look at it?

Comment: It's not publicly available and doing so would get me in trouble. :(

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help... I would look for something, anything that changes on the page once the radio button is selected. I think in cases like this it's not bad to use a `Thread.sleep()`. Sometimes you have to use it because there's no other option.

Comment: I see what your saying by looking for something that changes, a class does get added to a parent `li` tag to highlight the selection when the RB gets selected, I'll remember that for the future. The problem is selenium isn't selecting the RB at all, even though all indications say the RB exists when trying to select it. Anyways, I'll go with the `Thread.sleep` and re-investigate this at a later time. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Well ... from what you've said, it sounds like Selenium is clicking the radio button because you mentioned earlier that if you place a breakpoint or use Thread.sleep() it works eventually. It sounds to me like the page is just responding to the click really slowly and ideally you'd have a way to detect when the page is done processing the click so your script can move on.